# Where did my votes go? (on Q and A, not elections)

Tags: bug, voting

[I vote a lot on ServerFault:](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all) I've used up the maximum 40 votes per day almost every day for over a year, and for various reasons, I keep track of my voting, recording daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly/total votes every day.

A few months ago the rules were changed so that your vote count didn't change if you had voted on a question that was deleted.  Prior to that, I had noticed my vote count "mysteriously" dropping by a vote or two every now and then.

But in the past two days, it's been happening again.

Today, I cast 41 votes (there's another - related? - glitch that sometimes allows you to vote more than 40 times per day), but my weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly/all-time counts only went up 38.

Yesterday, I cast 40 votes and my weekly/monthly/quarterly counts went up by 40, but yearly and all-time counts only went up by 39.

It's obviously not a big deal, just a few votes here and there, but I'd like to know why it's happening when votes are supposed to count "forever" even if the question they were cast on goes away.

Comment: Why does everyone have the same gravatar? lol

Comment: Just a coincidence?

Comment: Or, we decided to stage Bastard Operator From Hell Gravatar week. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3368/bofh-gravatar-week

Comment: You can get more than 40 votes if a post you vote on gets deleted the same day. You can "reuse" that vote (the same day). Don't know about the aggregates counts though.